# Capture first decimal number which is >= 10 in Regex Ruby

Tags: regex, ruby

Already managed to capture the first decimal number from a given string thru

`^\D*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)`

See: https://rubular.com/r/5WJw7OkQ36iaQI

^ From the example, I need to capture 50, not 2.

I need to just capture any decimal number which is not less than 10 - so to avoid capturing non prices values.

I just want to capture the prices given by the clients, not the hours taken and some other random stuff they've given.

Is there a way for this? Thanks.

Comment: if you just want to capture any number greater than 10, how about just `/[0-9]{2,}/` ?
maybe you could give some more examples it would be easier to suggest a solution

Comment: An example would be https://rubular.com/r/5WJw7OkQ36iaQI - Don't want to capture the 2 but the 50. If that is the only way for me to get price values from responses. I can't capture just by nearby `$` because other clients do not put `$` on sentences :-)

Comment: already had a look at that example. did you try the regex which I mentioned in first comment ?

Comment: You are using an example to explain what you want to do. That rarely results in a precise, unambiguous question and your question is not exception. For example, what is the desired return value in the following strings?: `'2.50 35'` or `'007 19'` or `'5 7'` or....? Get the idea? You can use examples to illustrate what you want but you must first state the general problem without reference to an example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : You are right. Probably the word "decimal number" was incorrectly used by the OP and he wanted to say something like "natural number". He said he wants to capture currencies, and the user name sound Japanese, so with Japanese currency, there would be indeed no need for a fractional part. But it is still unclear how he wants to distinguish between numbers representing currency, and numbers representing working hours, since people might well work more than 10 hours per day (especially in Japan)  ;-)

Comment: @user1934428, Japanese Iabor law limits work weeks to five eight-hour days but I understand there are workarounds and that many Japanese love to party with their co-workers after work.

Comment: In theory, you are right. In theory, they even can take vacation. I think all of my Japanese friends, who happen to be employee, would laugh aloud if they would read your comment, because the reality looks different. Well, if we count only *payed* hours instead of working hours, maybe the law will be fulfilled sometimes, though recently, companies indeed seem to pay the overtime hours.

Answer (score 0):

I like to do something like,

```
/^(?<hours>\d+).+\$(?<price>\d+)/
```

I like to label groups because it helps me to understand/maintain regexp in the future but obviously you can do

```
^.+\$(?<price>\d+)
```

and will also work

Example how to use it...

```
2.6.4 :041 > m="2 hrs for $50".match(/^(?<hours>\d+).+\$(?<price>\d+)/)
 => #<MatchData "2 hrs for $50" hours:"2" price:"50">
2.6.4 :042 > m["price"]
 => "50"
2.6.4 :043 > m["hours"]
 => "2"
2.6.4 :044 > m="2 hrs for $50".match(/^.+\$(?<price>\d+)/)
 => #<MatchData "2 hrs for $50" price:"50">
2.6.4 :045 > m["price"]
 => "50"
```

Since you have $ character you dont need to check if less than 10 to know that is a price.

Comment: What if the string were `'2 hrs 5 dollars'`?

Comment: then we need more examples, because that is not what he said and you can do something like /[1-9][0-9]+/, but... what happens if ... "20 hrs $4 dollars"???.

Comment: More examples may be helpful but they are not a substitute for a clear statement of the question, which has not been provided.

Answer (score 0):

You already got a good answer about other approaches, but to answer your question directly:

> I need to just capture any decimal number which is not less than 10

`/[1-9][0-9]+/` will capture the first number greater-than-or-equal-to 10. In your example, it returns `50` instead of `2`.

Comment: What if the string were `'2.50'`?

Comment: Fair enough -- if decimal support was needed, I'd change it to:
`/[1-9][0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?/

Comment: I was not really saying that the string might be `'2.50'`. I don't know that. Nor do I know if the OP really means "decimal number" in view of the lone example given. When a question is unclear, as this one is, the OP must be required to clarify. That is not only necessary for readers to provide useful answers but demanding a minimum of rigor is good training for askers as well; if they cannot ask a clear question they will not be able to function effectively in the workspace. (Recall you need to include usernames in comments for the intended recipient to be notified of the comment by SO.)